# Creating a covid-19 app and im getting issues with the API being dynamic

Tags: javascript, api

Im working on a Coronavirus application. And im using this API: https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/south-africa

In my application a user is supposed to type the name of any given country and it should display the numbers of deaths, confirmed cases, recovered people. I keep getting a 404 error.

HTML & CSS can be found here:
https://github.com/Kazim786/coronavirus-updates/blob/master/index.html
https://github.com/Kazim786/coronavirus-updates/blob/master/style.css
(havent done much styling yet)

Here is my  Javascript code:

```
// The api: https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/south-africa

// const theCountries = await axios.get(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/south-africa`)
//         console.log(theCountries.data[0].Confirmed)
//         console.log(theCountries.data[0].Deaths)
//         console.log(theCountries.data[0].Recovered)

const countries = document.getElementById('countries').value

const results = document.getElementsByClassName('results')

const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')

const data = []
console.log(countries)

//Async Function
//`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${countries}`
console.log(byCountries())
async function byCountries(){
    try {
        const theCountries = await axios.get(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${countries}`)
        const deaths = theCountries.data[0].Deaths
        const confirmed = theCountries.data[0].Confirmed
        const recovered = theCountries.data[0].Recovered
        data.push(deaths, confirmed, recovered)
        console.log(theCountries)
        await console.log(data)
    }

    catch{
        console.log("Error");
    }
    
}

//Show results function:

function showResults(){
    if (countries !== null){
        results.innerHTML = `${countries} has number of deaths, confirmed cases, recovery as the following: ${data}. `
    } else {
        results.innerHTML = 'Enter a name of a Valid Country'
    }

}


//Add Event Listener

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', showResults)
```

Comment: just basic js, you need populate countries on submit, not as the page loads (else its not going to contain anything)

Comment: Thank you Lawrence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the result while the input field is empty as js loads.
You can make the submit button call both `byCountries()` and `showResults()`, and you'll also need to fetch the value inside byCountries()

```js
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    byCountries()
    showResults()
})
```

```js
async function byCountries(){
    try {
        const countries = document.getElementById('countries').value
        const theCountries = await axios.get(`https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/${countries}`)
...
```

Comment: Thank you Khaled. Can you also tell me why the showResults() function is not working? It is supposed to show the spans innerText. But it wont show it. It also doesnt display the span at the bottom of the input

Comment: getElementByClassName returns HTMLCollection type which is an array, you are not modifying the innerHTML of the span.
try using an id instead.

Comment: It still is not showing. I provided the link to my github. So you can look at the HTML, Javascript, and CSS

Comment: You'll also need to await the byCountries() call, `async () => {
    await byCountries()
    showResults()
}`

Comment: Thank you it worked! Can you explain why I had to do ```async () => {     await byCountries()     showResults() }```

Comment: byCountries is asynchronous, so code is not executed in a linear order. by awaiting the byCountries() call to finish, then you'll ensure data is populated correctly.
You can read more about asynchronous functions and async/await.